# Codeigniter Controller Failing due to Encoding Of Params In URL

Tags: codeigniter, encoding, uri

I have a URL as shown Below In codeigniter .

http://localhost/project/index.php/controller/function/aa aa aa /19

I get a PAGE NOT FOUND error due to encoding of the param (aa aa aa) as aa%20aa%20aa%20 . Is there any configuration in Codeigniter . So that My URL params are passed to my controller as they appear in URL .

Answer (score 1):

Url's are percent encoded. There is nothing wrong with url. I suspect you are having one or both of following 2 problems.
1) unless you have a function called function, you don't need thAt function in the url.
2) you are passing one extra space after "as as aa". You can't possibly have a function with space in d end

Comment: Suppose I am having a username as Foo Bar , which i want to pass as param to my controller function . Then What can I do to get The param as it is in controller function